# Error during installing cmake-js/fastcall

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-2015, npm, cmake

Trying to install cmake-js/fastcall:

```
npm install fastcall
```

getting error:

```
ERR! OMG There is no Visual C++ compiler installed. Install Visual C++ Build Toolset or Visual Studio.
....
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "fastcall"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! fastcall@0.2.3 install: `cmake-js compile`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fastcall@0.2.3 install script 'cmake-js compile'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm     installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the fastcall     package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
```

Visual Studio 2015 Community is installed, i can compile c++ code very well from there..

following not solved the problem:

```
set VisualStudioVersion=14.0
call c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat
npm install fastcall --msvs_version=2015
```

and there is nothing in log, nothing in google! Need your help. Where to look?

Comment: Your problem is unrelated to CMake. You don't show CMake code and this is not a CMake error.

Comment: however, how could i diagnose this? still no clue!!! should i install cmake? or is cmake-js full javascript implementation (and i do not require regular cmake)? should i make any further configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing cmake-3.8.0-rc1-win64 fully solved the problem!